# Access pod using ip

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service exposed, where behind we have several pods for that service. All the traffic to the pods are routed by LB as default .

Now I'm trying to access  to one particular `pod` using the `ip` from another `pod` of another service.

Unfortunately I cannot reach it, and is only through the `service` name defined as usual.

But I need to access to a specific pod since my comunicación let a request open there, and I need to go back to that particular pod,
Once I finish my journey.

There's any way to accomplish this, or is totally imposible.

Session affinity won’t help me.
This is the flow. Service A pod1 call Service B pod2 passing in the header the local ip. Then pod2 try to call the pod1 using the ip instead the service-name

Regards

Comment: do you mean cluster ip or node ip? it's the former that works.

Comment: You should be able to. every pod can reach any other pod unless you have a `NetworkPolicy` enabled. Give more details.

Comment: What kind of details do you need?

Comment: I think the question was not very clear. I improve the details

Comment: What CNI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

pods are scaled out and scaled down. pod ip is ephemeral and cant be relied on. Instead define a service that selects the required pods using selector. you should be accessing the pod using the service.

Comment: We create hateoas Uri that are very ephemeral as well and live with the life of the pod. I need to know if is technical possible. Ver expose the cluster of pods by service as well of course.

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 0):

Pods IPs are ephemeral so they are most likely to change every time a pod is re-created. Nevertheless you can check the Kubernetes documentation about [DNS for Pods and services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields). You can setup for your pods a `hostname` and `subdomain` so you can reach them via DNS like `hostname.subdomain.namespace.svc.cluster.local`.

You also may use [Headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services). This will give you the IP of one of the pods behind the service and not the service IP, for example:

```
# nslookup my-not-headless-svc
Server:     10.43.0.10
Address:    10.43.0.10:53

Name:   my-not-headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.43.55.35


# nslookup my-headless-svc
Name:   my-headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.42.3.103
Name:   my-headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.42.2.236
Name:   my-headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.42.2.227
```

Here you can clearly see, using a headless service you will always get one of the pod IPs behind the service and not the serviceIP itself.

Comment: I cannot direct access the pod from ServiceA from another pod from ServiceB using directly the ip.

Comment: If you cannot reach other pods in your cluster, then you have a problem with your CNI. Which CNI are you using? Can you check your kube-system and check for the cni pod logs? Are the pods you try to reach on different nodes? Are pods reachable within the same node?